# Javascript replace <ul> class name

Tags: javascript

For A/B testing purposes i'd like to change the class name of an  element. I can add Javascript to the A/B testing tool to achieve this. As i'm quite new to javascript, i could use some help.

The current  element:

```
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-4-col first last odd">
```

Must be changed to:

```
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-3-col first last odd">
```

How can i perform this by using Javascript?

Comment: read up about classList https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList.
document.getElementById(...).classList.remove(...)
/ classList.add(...)

Comment: This is introductory level stuff that should be covered by any introductory tutorial to client side JavaScript. Stackoverflow expects [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

use the below code:-

```
<script>
if (document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].classList.contains('products-grid--max-4-col') ){
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].classList.remove('products-grid--max-4-col');
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].classList.add('products-grid--max-3-col');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me.

Comment: @WVD welcome accept it.

Comment: What if the desired `ul` element is not the first one?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  according to requirment change the array index like [1].. .

Comment: @Anuppandey Consider not encouraging writing brittle code?